# Parsing not working correctly for Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

I have written the following logic to check status of service:

```
$status=@()

if($var1 -match "True") {
Write-Output "Service Enabled"
} else {
$status+="Service not Enabled"
Write-Output "Service not Enabled"
}

if($status.count -le 1){
    $returnStatus = "PASS"    
}else{
    $o=$status -join ", "
    $returnStatus = "FAIL- $o"
}

$getstatus = $returnStatus
```

When, I set `$var1 = false` the output should be `Service not Enabled` but it is not correct.

It seems that the issue is with `$status` always having a count of `1`even when it is `PASS`
Please suggest if there is a better logic to do the same logic.

Comment: There is no execution path in that code which would result in `Service not Enabled` being written to output.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I'd recommend using `$True` and `$False` (note the `$`). So you set `$var1 = $False` and then test using `if ($var1)` rather than `-match` on a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the variable name `$returnsStatus` / `$returnStatus`

Which causing final output `$getstatus` inconsistent.

Please fix variable name and try again.

## Proposed Solution

```
$status=@()

if($var1 -match "True") {
    Write-Output "Service Enabled"
} else {
    $status+="Service not Enabled"
    # Fixed Message
    Write-Output "Service not Enabled"
}

# Fix comparison from -le to -lt
if($status.count -lt 1){
    $returnStatus = "PASS"    
}else{
    $o=$status -join ", "
    $returnStatus = "FAIL- $o"
}

$getstatus = $returnStatus
```

Comment: I am getting same result even after updating `$returnStatus`

Comment: It seems that the issue is with `$status` always having a count of 1 even when it is `PASS` Please suggest if there is a better logic to do the same logic.

Comment: @meallhour what's the same result you are getting? in the updated code you had printed same `Service Enabled` in two places.

Comment: Updated my question. I am getting `Service Enabled` in both cases.

Comment: change comparison from `-le` (less than or equal) to `-lt` (less than)